# Tool to validate a USB device descriptor

Tags: usb

Is there a tool to validate a USB device descriptor that is read during the enumeration process? I have encountered situations where the USB device descriptors from devices I purchased (lab equipment) are not quite valid and fail to be properly identified by the operating system with a "failed to load device descriptor".  I know this is not always due to a corrupt device descriptor, but I know it sometimes is, in particular when it works on Windows but not macOS. Again, I understand I need macOS drivers for a particular device, but a corrupt USB device descriptor blocks the enumeration process and any driver I may have does not get a chance to get loaded. I have not found a descriptor validator: I would like to confirm that the descriptor is invalid before starting to fix this problem.

I have read the USB standard, and of course, I can catch obvious bugs (configuration number labelled '0' for instance used to be common and OSes had a workaround), but I cannot catch more subtle errors.

Answer (score 0):

I've had some hints from this tool:

https://www.thesycon.de/eng/usb_descriptordumper.shtml

It basically dumps the descriptor, and if it finds some errors in it, it will tell you something like: Error: expecting this value instead of the presented one.

Not much and sadly only for windows, but it helped me.